# active admin how to display name of collection select insted of id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, activeadmin

I got this error

```
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x00007fb013333018>
```

I need to display product name

```
f.input :product_ids , :as => :select, :collection => Product.all.collect {|product| [product.name, product.id] }
```

here is my codes

```
ActiveAdmin.register Case do
permit_params  :user_id, :product_ids ,:step_ids , :pt_first_name,:pt_last_name, :date_received, :due_date, :shade, 
              :mould, :upper_lower

  index do
    column do |user|
  link_to :id, doctor_path(user.id)
end
    column :pt_first_name
    column :pt_last_name
    column "product" do |m|
      u=Product.find(m.product_ids).name
    end
    column :user
    column :product
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end
  
form do |f|
        f.inputs do
        f.input :user
        f.input :pt_first_name
        f.input :pt_last_name
        f.input :date_received
        f.input :due_date
        f.input :shade
        f.input :mould
        f.input :upper_lower
        f.input :product_ids , :as => :select, :collection => Product.all.collect {|product| [product.name, product.id] }
        f.input :step_ids , :as => :select, :collection => Step.all.collect {|step| [step.name, step.id] }
        end
        actions 
      end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
u=Product.find(m.product_ids).name
```

`product_ids` is array of product ids.

`.find` will returns an array for objects if you pass multiple ids or array of ids, so `.name` will not directly work on result as it `array`.

you can use either of following options

- Using `find` & `map`

```
    column "product" do |m|
      Product.find(m.product_ids).map(&:name).join(', ')
    end
```

- Using `where` & `map`

```
    column "product" do |m|
      Product.where(id: m.product_ids).map(&:name).join(', ')
    end
```

- Using `where` & `pluck`

```
    column "product" do |m|
      Product.where(id: m.product_ids).pluck(:name).join(', ')
    end
```

Comment: how can i disply the product name in the show section?

Comment: @nourza you need to add block for show page and on instance of record you can just do `instance.name.join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 6.0.0 on MRI 2.6.3, this worked for me:

```
f.select :product_ids, Product.all.collect { |prod| [prod.name, prod.id] }, {}, { multiple: true }
```

Comment: I need to display the products name in show here column :product_ids . what you wrote is for adding new or edit the product